# How are two numbers multiplied in Python? What is the associated time complexity?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning about Karatsuba and was curious how Python actually implements the multiplication operation. Sorry but I couldn't find the documentation for this.

Comment: @KentKostelac You make it sound like Python's numbers have fixed size (like 32 or 64 bits). The question is alright as it is, while your comment rather seems to be missing the point.

Comment: @KentKostelac "multiplying numbers that can't be stored in 64bit registers" is quite clearly what this question is about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on the types of the numbers you are multiplying:

#### For floating point numbers

The Python objects representing the multiplicands are converted to C `double`s and multiplied in C.

```
static PyObject *
float_mul(PyObject *v, PyObject *w)
{
    double a,b;
    CONVERT_TO_DOUBLE(v, a);
    CONVERT_TO_DOUBLE(w, b);
    a = a * b;
    return PyFloat_FromDouble(a);
}
```

As far as I know the time complexity here is not relevant since the numbers are fixed precision and multiplying any two floating point numbers together should use the same number of operations.

Of course in the end this is all handled by the CPU, where floating point operations might be more or less optimised depending on your architecture.

#### For small integers

From the comments in [the CPython project](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/longobject.c#L76)

> For int multiplication, use the O(N**2) school algorithm unless both
> operands contain more than KARATSUBA_CUTOFF digits (this being an internal Python int digit, in base BASE)

`KARATSUBA_CUTOFF` turns out to be `70`, so for multiplications where one of the multiplicands has `70` digits or less, your multiplication will be `O(N^2)` You can find the (lengthy) code for that [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/longobject.c#L3346).

#### For big integers

If both integers have more than `70` digits, then the Karatsuba algorithm that you've been learning about is used. You can see the implementation [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/longobject.c#L3485).

#### For complex numbers

As you would expect, the real and imaginary parts are [split up](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/complexobject.c#L54) and the required operations are done as above.

And finally, there are lots of shortcuts for edge cases like multiplication by zero, or single digit multiplicands, that are scattered throughout the codebase.

Comment: What do you mean with "digit"?

Comment: I've added a final part of the Cpython comment which explains. It the number of digits in the number represented in the base which you are operating in Python (not binary digits for example)

Comment: I'd say if you mention the specific cutoff at 70 digits, it would be good to also say the base, otherwise it's a bit odd. Like if you asked me how much I paid for my computer and I tell you "628", but you have no idea what currency I'm using so the "628" is somewhat useless :-). Although I acknowledge that for the complexity question it's irrelevant...